# py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. % get_backend())

Tags: faster-rcnn

I was trying to run the Mask-RCNN repository provided by the matterport  in Github. https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN. when I run the demo in the anaconda, it showed `"C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. % get_backend()) "`. Is there someone came cross the similar problem?

Comment: Check if the code has at some point something like "matplotlib.use('Agg')" and remove this line. It supresses the plot windows during training.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to plot on a remote server, ssh X11 forwarding can then be used to display matplotlib plots.

Try to use this,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
```

Make sure you have XMing or XQuartz (if you're on mac), and use -Y

> $ shh -Y username@servidorIP

Answer (score 0):

Enter or change the line in ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc starting with "backend : " in:
backend      : tkagg